# Fatal Error on wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I came back to my site after a long break and TADAH : Fatal error: Call to undefined function update_post_caches() in /home/web/cote-image/port2016/wp-includes/query.php on line 3818

You can see that on : http://lpb.cerealog.net/cote-image/port2016/.

Have you some answer to help me ?

I remove all the plugins for test but nothing

I think it was an update 4.6.1 to 4.6.3 but i don't have idea.

Comment: Try backing up and updating to the latest 4.7.2 release,

Also turn off each plugin one by one and refresh.

it sounds like W3 Cache might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by **[W3 Total Cache](https://bg.wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/)** plugin. You should disable and enable it again or better update it if it is not the latest version. If you still experience the problem try renaming or removing the `w3-total-cache` folder.
Here is more regarding this issue https://wordpress.org/support/topic/call-to-undefined-function-wp_cache_get/

Comment: i don't have cach plugin